# How to Scope in NLog Properties on Request to Server?

Tags: asp.net, nlog

So inside the header of my request, I am passing a few values that I want to include for logging purposes, currently, I am scoping the values like this:

```cs
public async Task<List<VALUES>> Get()
        {
            var req = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            logger.PushScopeProperty("RequestEndpoint", req.Url.LocalPath);
            logger.PushScopeProperty("RequestUser", req.Headers["UserId"]);
            logger.PushScopeProperty("FE_URL", req.Headers["FE_URL"]);

        }
```

The issue with this method is that I have to do it for each endpoint I have, which will take up a tremendous amount of time.

My current method was to try to scope them in through the `Global.asax` (It's a .Net Framework 4.7.2 project) file like so:

```cs
protected void Application_BeginRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var req = context.Request;
            logger.PushScopeProperty("RequestEndpoint", req.Url.LocalPath);
            logger.PushScopeProperty("RequestUser", req.Headers["UserId"]);
            logger.PushScopeProperty("FE_URL", req.Headers["FE_URL"]);
        }
```

But it didn't work. So is it possible to auto scope in the values when a request is received? I know very little about middleware, don't know if that's something that I can use in this scenario or not.

Comment: Maybe consider using HttpContext.Items-dictionary to insert the values, and then use [${aspnet-item:MyKeyId}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetItem-layout-renderer) in the NLog Target Layout to output the value. Notice that [NLog.Web.AspNetCode](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore) includes many [NLog AspNet LayoutRenderers](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web.aspnetcore) ex. also for outputting HTTP-Headers.